# react-native android url images not displayed

Tags: android, react-native

Dynamic images displayed using uri from remote is not getting displayed in android emulator. whereas this works perfectly fine in ios.

```
<Image source={uri: 'https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/react_thumb_install.png'} style = {{height: 200, resizeMode : 'stretch', margin: 5 }} />
```

Do we have to do any additional configuration in android to display remote images. pls help.

Comment: Have you given this uri as source in Image tag?

Comment: yes... I added the uri as source in image tag

Comment: use double braces like source = {{uri:'image_url'}}

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<Image   
     onLoad={() => this.forceUpdate()}    
     resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.cover}  
     source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}} 
     style = {styles.imageStyle} />
```

with this style

```
 imageStyle:{
    height:100,
    width:100,    
  }
```